# How get data from javascript using HtmlUnit?

Tags: htmlunit

How get data from javascript using HtmlUnit ?

Title: total shoots

[screen html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0627I.png)

```
public static void getElements() {
    try (
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("some URL");
        final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("in-game-stats");

        System.out.println(div.getTextContent());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what else ?

Comment: Hat is the problem? What output di you get, what do you expect? In general it is often more useful to use `.asXml()` while developing because you can see the xml instead only the displayed content.

Comment: Expect get data from html generated by javascript like on screen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find the script element. Because you script tag has no id attribute doing something like 'page.getHtmlElementById' is not the right way. HtmlUnit offers many different ways for find elements. As starting point have a look at the documentation (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html).
Next step will be to get the javascript from the HtmlStript. If the script code is embedded inside the script tag you can simply use asXml().

Comment: Result use method asXml() : http://wklej.org/id/2936076/                                     code: http://prntscr.com/d2k13g

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to process javascript objects , but you can parse  tag and have it parsed by self.

Use `(HtmlElement).asText();`
to extract data from div tag.